Word VBA Macro for linearizing tables is removing superscript
I am currently working with a macro that grabs text from a two column header table and takes it out of the cell basically stacks it. The issue I am having is that when it does that it removes the superscript, here's an example.
Test:



This is a Test
This is a Test




This is a ®Test r1c1
This is a Test r1c2


This is a Test r2c1
This is a ®Test r2c2



Result should be:

This is a Test r2c1
This is a Test: This is a Test® r2c2

What I get is:

This is a Test r2c1
This is a Test: This is a Test ® r2c2

Not sure if it shows, but basically as I've mentioned, it removes the superscripting, here's the macro I am working with:
Private Enum bwTableType
    ColumnHeader = 0
    TwoColumnHeader = 1
End Enum

Private Enum bwTableStructure
    bwRowNum = 0
    bwColNum = 1
    bwHasContent = 2
    bwMaxColCount = 3
    bwMaxRowCount = 4
End Enum

Public Sub TblLinearizer_Two_Column_Header()
    
    Dim recordName As String: recordName = "TblLinearizer_Two_Column_Header"
    Dim UR As UndoRecord: Set UR = Application.UndoRecord
    UR.StartCustomRecord recordName
    
    If Selection.Tables.Count = 1 Then
        Dim curTable As Table: Set curTable = Selection.Tables(1)
        TblPrep curTable
        
        If curTable.Uniform Then
            If BoldTextPresentInFirstColumn(curTable) Then TblHeadersUp
            SchwabTblSetup curTable
            
            Dim tableData As Collection: Set tableData = New Collection
            Dim curRowID As Long: Dim curColID As Long
            Dim rowItem As Variant: Dim rowItems() As String: Dim rowStyles() As String
            Dim destinationRange As Range
            Dim tmpIntStr As String: Dim tmpStr As String
            Dim curCell As String: Dim curCol1Header As String: Dim curCol2Header As String: Dim curRowHeader As String
            Dim WorkingRange As Range
            
        'Destination
            Set destinationRange = GetDestinationRange(curTable)
        'Pull Header String Into Table
            PullHeaderStringIntoTable curTable, bwTableType.TwoColumnHeader
            
        'Collect Table Body
            tmpStr = vbNullString
            tmpIntStr = vbNullString
            For curRowID = 1 To curTable.Rows.Count
                tmpStr = vbNullString
                tmpIntStr = vbNullString
                If curRowID > 2 Then
                    ReDim rowData(0, 1) As String
                    For curColID = 1 To curTable.Columns.Count
                        curCell = Left(curTable.cell(curRowID, curColID).Range, Len(curTable.cell(curRowID, curColID).Range) - 2)
                        curCol1Header = Left(curTable.cell(1, curColID).Range, Len(curTable.cell(1, curColID).Range) - 2)
                        curCol2Header = Left(curTable.cell(2, curColID).Range, Len(curTable.cell(2, curColID).Range) - 2)
                        curRowHeader = Left(curTable.cell(curRowID, 1).Range, Len(curTable.cell(curRowID, 1).Range) - 2)
                        If curColID > 1 Then
                            If curRowHeader = vbNullString Then
                                If Not curCell Like "Accrued*" Then
                                    If Not curCol2Header = vbNullString Then
                                        tmpIntStr = tmpIntStr & "3-5" & "|"
                                        tmpStr = tmpStr & curCol2Header & ": " & curCell & "|"
                                    Else
                                        tmpIntStr = tmpIntStr & "3-5" & "|"
                                        tmpStr = tmpStr & curCol1Header & ": " & curCell & "|"
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    tmpIntStr = tmpIntStr & "1-3" & "|"
                                    tmpStr = tmpStr & curCol1Header & ": " & curCell & "|"
                                End If
                            Else
                                If Not UCase(curRowHeader) = "COST BASIS" _
                                And Not UCase(curRowHeader) Like "Accrued*" Then
                                    If Not curCol1Header = vbNullString Then
                                        tmpIntStr = tmpIntStr & "3-5" & "|"
                                        tmpStr = tmpStr & curCol1Header & ": " & curCell & "|"
                                    Else
                                        tmpIntStr = tmpIntStr & "3-5" & "|"
                                        tmpStr = tmpStr & curCol2Header & ": " & curCell & "|"
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    If Not curCell = vbNullString Then
                                        tmpIntStr = tmpIntStr & "1-3" & "|"
                                        tmpStr = tmpStr & curRowHeader & ": " & curCell & "|"
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        Else
                            If curCell = vbNullString Then
                                tmpIntStr = tmpIntStr & "1-1" & "|"
                                tmpStr = tmpStr & "|"
                            Else
                                If Not UCase(curRowHeader) = "COST BASIS" _
                                And Not UCase(curRowHeader) Like "Accrued*" Then
                                    tmpIntStr = tmpIntStr & "1-5" & "|"
                                    tmpStr = tmpStr & curCell & "|"
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                    rowData(0, 0) = Left(tmpIntStr, Len(tmpIntStr) - 1)
                    rowData(0, 1) = Left(tmpStr, Len(tmpStr) - 1)
                    tableData.Add rowData
                End If
            Next
    
        'Prep Destination
            destinationRange.InsertParagraphAfter
            destinationRange.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("1-1")
            
        'Linearize
            Dim i As Long
            For Each rowItem In tableData
                rowItems() = Split(rowItem(0, 1), "|", -1, vbBinaryCompare)
                rowStyles() = Split(rowItem(0, 0), "|", -1, vbBinaryCompare)
                With destinationRange
                    For i = 0 To UBound(rowItems)
                        .Paragraphs.Last.Previous.Range.InsertAfter rowItems(i) & Chr(13)
                        .Paragraphs.Last.Previous.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(rowStyles(i))
                    Next
                    .Paragraphs.Last.Previous.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
                    .Paragraphs.Last.Previous.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("1-1")
                End With
            Next
            
        'Delete Original
            curTable.Delete
        'Cleanup
            PostLinearizeCleanup destinationRange
        Else
            MsgBox "Currently selected table is uneven."
        End If
    End If
    
    UR.EndCustomRecord
End Sub

Private Sub PostLinearizeCleanup(ByRef curRange As Range)
    'Text
    With BWFinds
        Set .DocumentRange = ActiveDocument.Range
        Set .WorkingRange = curRange
        .SetWildCardDefaults
        .FindAndReplaceAll "[!^13:]{2,}: ^13", "", curRange
        .FindAndReplaceAll "[ ]{1,}(: )", "\1", curRange
        .FindAndReplaceAll "[ ]{2,}", " ", curRange
        .FindAndReplaceAll "[^13]{3,}", "^p^p", curRange
        .FindAndReplaceAll "^13: ", "^p", curRange
        .FindAndReplaceAll "[A-z ]{1,}: (Accrued [A-z]{1,}: )", "\1", curRange
    End With
    
'Formatting
    curRange.Bold = False
End Sub

I tried adding .FormattedText and the end of some statement but it still removes the superscript, any help is appreciated.
NOTE: Any item with BW comes from a BWFinds class item that I utilize, I can add those as needed
Public Sub FindAndReplaceAll(ByVal findPattern As String, ByVal replacePattern As String, _
                            Optional ByRef searchRange As Variant)
    
    SetWorkingRange searchRange
    
    With workingRange_.Find
        ResetFandRProperties workingRange_
        .Text = findPattern
        .Replacement.Text = replacePattern
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub


It's not clear from your formatting what exactly you have in the document. E.g. do you have the literal characters <sup>?

Have you tried converting the table to text first, and then processing the returned range? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.table.converttotext

@GSerg The  was meant to denote that at that point the registered trademark was superscripted and when it doesn't have it then it wasn't superscripted, sorry for the confusion. Its just regular text? like i open the word doc, highlight the table and run the macro on it

The basic problem is that in Word, .Range.Text always returns plain text, with no formatting. So as soon as you have copied those cell contents into strings, all the formatting has gone. So you either have to record how it was formatted, or you have to know how every character need to be formatted (in your Cleanup routine I would guess). Faced with this problem, I would probably do something like : record the range of each cell's text; when inserting at your destination, perhaps use .Rage.FormattedText = therecordedrange.FormattedText...

...or yit might be simpler to copy the range. Then "tidy up" that range. Yes, find/replaces should be quick but depending on what you actually need to do it might be simpler to @tidy up@ character by character. cf. "TimothyRylatt's suggestion - in either case, you have to avoid losing the formatting in the first place. Oh, by the way, trying to copy a .FormattedText into a String will also lose the formatting. No idea what happens if you copy into a Variant, but the result probably won't be a String either.
